# How Can I Customize the List of Facebook Pages During the OAuth 2.0 Process?

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

I have a social media tool that posts items for users on a scheduled basis, so I gather and store page access tokens for Facebook using OAuth 2.0.  All that works great, but the problem is when large agencies try to add new pages for their clients - they check the new page they want to add, and then the previously saved access tokens for the older pages get inactivated.

My question is, is it possible to customize that OAuth dialog so that I display the list of pages myself, in my own application UI?  That way I can keep those previous pages hardcoded as checked.  The docs don't show any way, and yet I have seen other sites do this. Here's an example from another social media site:

[image: FB Oauth dialog 1]

[image: FB Oauth dialog 2]

After clicking Continue on page 2, the website displays their own list of pages and checkboxes. I've tried to mimic that behavior with this bit of Javascript, but I still end up with that list of pages in the Facebook dialog. (I tried adding enable_profile_selector:false, but that doesn't seem to do anything.)

Any insight greatly appreciated.

```js
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : 'appid',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v10.0'
    });
  };

// on add channel click
function doFacebookLogin() {

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      requestFacebookPermissions();
    } else {
      FB.login(function(response) {
        console.log('doing initial login', response);
        if (response.authResponse)
          requestFacebookPermissions();
      }, {
        scope: 'public_profile,email'
      });
    }
  });
}

function requestFacebookPermissions() {
  FB.login(function(response) {
    console.log('requesting permissions', response);
    if (response.authResponse) {
      // handle returned access token....
    }
  }, {
    scope: 'pages_show_list,pages_manage_posts,pages_read_engagement,pages_read_user_content'
  });
}
```

```html
<script async="true" defer="defer" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
```

Update: Here is what my OAuth flow looks like.  The flow in the two screenshots above is superior, because the list of pages is buried behind the "Choose What You Allow Link." In my flow, I get an extra page asking "What pages do you want to use," and everything is unchecked by default.  How can I use the flow shown in the above screencaps?

[image]
[image]

Comment: The user must select the pages they want to allow access to via the login dialog, so any list of their pages your app would read afterwards, would be limited to those to begin with. Catch-22

Comment: @CBroe True, but the difference in the screenshots I posted above is that your pages are hidden behind that "Choose What You Allow" link, and they are all pre-checked. In my app, there's a third screen that appears that asks "What Pages do you want to use?" and they are all unchecked by default. Trying to figure out how to use the flow seen in the two screenshots above.

Comment: Have a link to the login for that first site? I don't think this is anything you can take any direct influence on, but I'd like to check if they are using some special parameters or configuration maybe, as far as that might be determinable from the public-facing code.

Comment: Not exactly public, but both buffer.com and socialpilot.co use that flow. You can sign up for a free trial, then add Facebook as a channel.

Comment: Seems like those other sites are somehow locked into older FB API versions.  You can tell by the UI that they're getting an older version of those dialogs, even though they all say v10 in the URL. I can sometimes get an older dialog to appear if I use v2.7 in my FB.init, but it won't stick through the whole oauth process.

Comment: Okay, i have the same question? RickTi, did you find answer for this?

Comment: I was not able to bend the FP API to do what I wanted, no. I just added more messaging around my workflow to try and make things clear to the user.