# How to ask all permissions for facebook/insta pages via facebook api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram

Hello and thank you for your time

When i used facebook SDK the workflow to let user connect his insta pages were - like

1. User logged into fb
2. Select Account
3. Select facebook page and check all permissions for this page
4. Select insta page and check all permission for this page
5. Install my application.

__

But i found, that in some applications you can you just click confirm okay one time (there is also button to see permissions and pages) and accept all permissions.

I checked this page - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v12.0#permissions but there is no any options for such settings.

Can you help me to understand where i can find such option?

__

The example i want to get:

[image]

The example i get now (ask permission for insta pages / facebook pages step by step)

[image]

Comment: Can you please take that screenshot in English, so that we can all understand what it says there?

Comment: Okay, i have the same question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69170347/how-can-i-customize-the-list-of-facebook-pages-during-the-oauth-2-0-process with no answer

Comment: I don't think there is anything you can do to influence this. The flow might perhaps differ based on what combination of permissions gets asked for, but asking for permissions is all you can do with the login dialog call, there are no other parameters that would influence its behavior in this way. And it is also possible that a "big player" like chatfuel gets special treatment, access to options normal 3rd-party apps don't. (F.e., I think Uber is able to access the Facebook user's mobile phone number, which is not generally possible for other apps.)